# C++ Language template question

Tags: c++, templates

Below is a small test case that demonstrates a problem that I am trying to solve using templates in C++:

```
template<typename T>
void
unused(T const &) {
  /* Do nothing. */
}

int main() {
  volatile bool x = false;
  unused(!x); // type of "!x" is bool
}
```

As written below, the g++ v3.4.6 compiler complains:

```
test.cc: In constructor `test::test()':
test.cc:11: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const volatile bool&' from expression of type 'volatile bool'
test.cc:3: error: in passing argument 1 of `void unused(const T&) [with T = volatile bool]'
```

The goal here is to have unused suppress unused variable warnings that occur in optimized code.  I have a macro that does an assertion check and in optimized code the assertion goes away, but I want any variables in the assertion's expression to remain referenced so that I don't get unused variable warnings only in optimized code.  In the definition for unused() template function, I use a reference so that no copy constructor code gets inadvertently run so that the call to unused can be completely elided by the compiler.

For those interested, the assertion macro looks like this:

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
#  define Assert(expression) unused(expression)
#else // not NDEBUG
#  define Assert(expression)      \
{         \
  bool test = (expression);      \
     \
  if (!test) {        \
    if (StopHere(__LINE__, __FILE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,  \
                    #expression, false)) {    \
      throw Exit(-1); /* So that destructors are run. */  \
    }         \
  }         \
}
#endif // else not NDEBUG
```

For the above test case, I can make the error go away by adding another similar unused function like this:

```
template<typename T>
void
unused(T const) {
  /* Do nothing. */
}
```

However, then other cases calling unused() fail due to ambiguity when the argument can be made a reference to with something like:

```
file.h:176: error: call of overloaded `unused(bool)' is ambiguous
myAssert.h:27: note: candidates are: void unused(T) [with T = bool]
myAssert.h:34: note:                 void unused(const T&) [with T = bool]
```

So my question is, how can I change unused() or overload it so that it meets the following requirements:

1. The call to unused() can be optimized away into a no-op by the compiler.

   It causes any variables that are present in the expression passed to unused() to appear used and thus not result in a warning about them being defined but not used.

   The argument to unused() may or may not be able to be referenced.

   The argument to unused() may be an object with an expensive copy constructor which should not be invoked when unused() is invoked.

Thanks.

-William

Comment: Rejecting the first snippet looks like a GCC error: the type of `!some_volatile_bool` is `bool` and not `volatile bool` - so `T` should be deduced to `bool`, not to `volatile bool`. Notice that rvalues of non-class types are never const/volatile qualified.

Comment: Reported it: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42655

Comment: For me, this looked like a duplicate of what Herb Sutter mentioned in his Blog, http://herbsutter.wordpress.com/2009/10/18/mailbag-shutting-up-compiler-warnings/ btw, which compiler are you using?

Comment: May be a bug, but if he's not calling `unused(readWriteActivated)`, that would sound like his intent anyway.

Comment: g++ v3.4.6, but the bug is also evident in these versions too: 4.0.0 4.1.0 4.2.0 4.3.0 4.4.0 4.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Johannes said in the comments, you hit a compiler bug. You can work around it by explicitly converting to `bool`:

```
unused( bool( !readWriteActivated) ); // add bool() to any (!volatile_bool_var)
```

---

#### Old answer (but still not a bad idea)

If I recall the const-volatile qualification rules, all you need is to qualify the dummy variable more. Essentially, you just want to parrot the error message back in the declared type :vP .

```
template<typename T>
void
unused(T const volatile &) { // only change is to add "volatile"
  /* Do nothing. */
}
```

Also, nice that you put the `const` after the type, where it belongs.

Comment: It is unclear that const 'belongs' in one place or the other, both are correct from a language definition.  Adding volatile does not resolve the issue: test.cc:11: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const volatile bool&' from expression of type 'volatile bool'
test.cc:3: error: in passing argument 1 of `void unused(const volatile T&) [with T = bool]'

Comment: Where const belongs is a matter of opinion. The code is actually fine with or without any qualifiers; the error indicates a compiler bug.

Comment: In my version of the compiler, v3.4.6, adding the cast to bool around the argument to unused() does not work around the bug.

Comment: Wow, that really sucks, and is pretty surprising. GCC 4 has been out for a while, though; maybe time to upgrade? I guess the next suggestion would be to cast to `int`, since in the bugzilla discussion they said the problem only affects `bool`.

Answer (score 3):

A common (and much simpler) way to achieve this is to just cast the result to `void`.

```
(void) x;
```

where x is some otherwise unreferenced value.

Comment: This is not correct. Still we get the warning. This code is only partly effective. It does not silence the warning on all compilers.

Comment: @Jagannath: I think that testing on a beta compiler isn't exactly fair game since you've said that VC2010 is the culprit. Try it on just about every other compiler that is actually...released.

Comment: @Evan: Agreed. Will try on other compilers and see.

Answer (score 2):

Charles Nicholson suggests doing something like this to mark unused variables for reasons explained in [this article](http://cnicholson.net/2009/02/stupid-c-tricks-adventures-in-assert/):

```
#define UNSUSED(a) ((void)sizeof(a))
```

The short version is... sizeof does not evaluate the expression, but compilers still count it as "used" when it's seen in this context.

I believe this satisfies all 4 of your criteria, specifically because sizeof() can take any valid expression, and because the expression will not be evaluated (and thus will not generate any code).

Answer (score 1):

The best solution that I've seen is like this:

```
#define UNUSED(x) ((void)x)
```

It is portable, and suppresses the warning successful.

**EDIT**:

since you've stated that this is more like an assertion, then you should probably do something like this:

```
#if defined ASSERT_ENABLED
#define TEST(test) (!(test)) ? assert_failed(# test, __FILE__, __LINE__) : (void)0    
#else
#define TEST(ignore) ((void)0)
#endif
```

This will produce no code unless `ASSERT_ENABLED` is defined and won't produce a warning about unused variables. This is pretty much how the `assert` macro in libc works.

I suppose the issue is that the variables are only used in the assertion, which is a poor way to do what you want. Why not mark it as unused and use the assertion macro **separately** that way it is clear that the variable isn't really used for anything, but you still get your debug build assertion. Just tackle the problems individually.

Comment: @Evan, did you complile this? I get the warning on VC2010.

Comment: @Jagannath: I've never used VC2010, but casting to void is supposed to be the correct solution and has worked on just about every compiler I've used before.

Comment: Shouldn't that be ((void)ignore) in the #else clause?

Comment: If you want just a plain old `assert` style test macro, then no. But if you like, you can do as you suggest and it'll work just fine. Like i just edit'ed in, I would tackled to the unused and assertion issues completely separately which avoids the whole problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change your definition of unused:

```
inline void unused(bool) {}
```

Since you already want an expression for which conversion to bool is required, this does that conversion and nothing else.  Inline allows the compiler to optimize, including in situations where the expression doesn't have side-effects (but you'll have to test to know exactly what happens in complex situations).

Additionally, this fixes a common problem with most assert macros: if the expression *does* have side-effects, those will always be evaluated.  (Depending on use, that can be very good or very bad.)

Comment: This will not work in general, for example, what if the argument to the assert cannot be cast to bool, hence the template.

Comment: You *already require this property* with your current macro, with `bool test = (expression);`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler warning has nothing to do with used or unused. You are passing a volatile variable - readWriteActivated - to a function which does not accept a volatile reference. Try a const cast.

Answer (score 0):

Why not skip templates altogether and go with the ellipses.

```
inline void unused (...) { /* do nothing */ }
```

Comment: Then throw an `&` in front of it.

Comment: Variadic functions must have at least one non-variadic parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to suppress the unused variable warning, why do you call it as
unused(!readWriteActivated);  ? Why can't you just call it as
unused(readWriteActivated); 
and make the code as

```
template<typename T>
void UnUsed(const T& )
{

}
```

For more references see the blog post from Herb Sutter [Here](http://herbsutter.wordpress.com/2009/10/18/mailbag-shutting-up-compiler-warnings/)

EDIT: Removed the parameter name in the function. This works for 
unused(!readWriteActivated); as well.

Comment: don't name the parameter or you'll get a warning that "ignore" is unused :-P.

Comment: Because the real code has an assertion of !readWriteActivated, in the optimized version the assertion goes away, but I don't want an unused variable warning when the assertion is the only usage of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug:

http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42655

There is no work around at the unused() level.  Instead, each occurrence may be worked around by introducing a temporary variable before calling unused():

```
template<typename T>
void
unused(T const &) {
  /* Do nothing. */
}

int main() {
  volatile bool x = false;
  bool avoidGCC42655 = !x; // type of "!x" is bool
  unused(avoidGCC42655);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why are you passing `!readWriteActivated` instead of `readWriteActivated` if the value of the expression doesn't matter?

Comment: I am not sure why this was down voted.. It is infact the appropriate question.

Comment: No the testcase is simplified.  In the real code the negation is needed because it is an assertion and remove the negation would give the wrong assertion.

Comment: @WilliamKF: if it is an assertion, then you should post code that demonstrates the usage you intend (are you trying to produce something like assert?)

Comment: I was trying to simplify the test case down to something small.  The assertion looks like:

#ifdef NDEBUG
#  define Assert(expression) unused(expression)
#else // not NDEBUG
#  define Assert(expression)      \
{         \
  bool test = (expression);      \
         \
  if (!test) {        \
    if (StopHere(__LINE__, __FILE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,  \
                    #expression, false)) {    \
      throw Exit(-1); /* So that destructors are run. */  \
    }         \
  }         \
}
#endif // else not NDEBUG